# "Окорочка"

Tags: лексика

Почему говорят "окорочок - окорочка", если множетвенное число от аналогичных слов образуется окончанием "-и": "новичок - новички", "сверчок - сверчки", "крючок - крючки"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова аналогичные только на первый взгляд. Суффиксы разные. Количество слогов тоже разное. Хотя вряд ли это влияет на выбор окончания. В русском языке окончание существительных множественного числа 2 склонения раньше было -Ы (У Пушкина - дОмы. сейчас домА). Окончание А более молодое. Поэтому наблюдаются колебания: директоры? директора?  и т.п. Поскольку слово окорочок достаточно новое (в словарях - окорок), то и окончание у него - "новое" - А. Да и у слова окорок множественное число - окорокА.